# Ninject Constructor injection and build problems

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject, asp.net-mvc-4

Inheriting from MVC Controller Class

```
public class BaseController  : Controller
{

    private ITenantRepository _repository;
    [Inject]
    public BaseController(ITenantRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
    protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);
    }
}
```

can't build

BaseController' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

clearly I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Ctrl-Alt-O, go see where you're doing a `new BaseController()` and pass in a mock/stub. But most imporantly, go look at one of the 50 tuttorials out there and save hyourself the trial and error. (Or even better, buy manning.com/seemann and flounder around even less). Note that [Inject] doesnt cause anything to happen by itself (in fact it's suprtfluous) - the `DependencyResolver` needs to be hooked into ASP.NET MVC's pipeline. See the NuGet Ninject.MVC3 package and associated docs on https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/MVC3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your child controllers make sure that you have defined a constructor with the same parameters as your base class:

```
public class FooController: BaseController
{
    public FooController(ITenantRepository repository): base(repository)
    {
    }

    ...
}
```

You need to do this because in the base class you have removed the parameterless constructor and replaced it with a custom one. So derived classes must also be removed from their parameterless constructor.

Also note that the normal way of using Ninject with ASP.NET MVC is to set it up as the `DependencyResolver` at the top level of your app. The controllers should not use any container-specific attributes such as the `[Inject]` attribute you used as these tie your code to the dependency injection container you are using.

Note as well that in addition to being bad practice from the preceding perspective, the `[Inject]` attribute on the constructor in your code has no material effect:

- Nothing is going to step in and say 'Look, it's got an attribute, we better provide its dependencies'
- If you do have Ninject configured as the DependencyResolver, it won't need the attribute as there's no ambiguity whatsoever as to what's needed to construct the controller

  - there's no default constructor
  - there's no competing constructor

Comment: [As you're obviously well aware] The Inject attribute has no purpose on a ctor even in Ninject other than to disambiguate constructor selection. The way you put it suggests to the uninformed that it might actually do something (by saying 'instead of' DependencyResolver.

Comment: @RubenBartelink, that's true. I have updated my post to reflect this.

Comment: Expanded my comment and edited in what I'd have said. Sorry if its mad long winded now. Hope a +1 makes up for that!